# Calling terminal.app with the commandline it should execute

Tags: macos, command-line

I use [Lazarus IDE](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/) to generate some content. Inside it I can set up external commands.

I can configure "Program name" and "Parameters"

I would like to set it up, so I from inside the software can call Terminal (or similar) to copy a file to speed up my work.

Do I need to create a script instead? Or is there a simple way I can use "Program name" and "Parameters" to execute command line commands?

Comment: What is that particular program you're using? Can this program also simply call shell scripts? Can you run a command-line?

Comment: Lazarus. I imagine it can call shell scripts - I have no tried - but I suppose it is a good solution (create . sh script that can do the copying). I have been a little hesitant to setup a scripted build process on my Mac, but I guess I may just as well bite the apple soon. However, if what I want is possible without it, I would that prefer that for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a Terminal window in which you can later run commands, call the following:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"ls -la ~/Desktop\""
```

Here, `osascript` can launch [AppleScript commands](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/02.html). The actual AppleScript command just, well, tells Terminal to run a script. Here, for example, it's a file listing of the desktop. You can also put your AppleScript into a separate `.scpt` file or edit it using Script Editor. This is a very macOS-specific way of doing system administration.

Otherwise – if you don't need a Terminal window open – it would make more sense to have your IDE call a shell script that performs your required setup in the background.

Comment: I will check it out - thank you. Upvoted for now.